# How do I replace values in certain columns conditional on a certain value in corresponding columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
`1_X94` <- c("apple", "lemon", "orange")
`2_X94` <- c("apple", "strawberry", "lemon")
`1_X09` <- c(1, 2, 3)
`2_X09` <- c(4, 5, 6)
`1_X38` <- c("red", "yellow", "orange")
`2_X38` <- c("red", "red", "yellow")
                    
df <- data.frame(`1_X94`, `2_X94`, `1_X09`, `2_X09`, `1_X38`, `2_X38`)
```

And I have a second data frame:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "watermelon")
fruit_list <- data.frame(fruit)
```

What I would like to accomplish is, whenever there is a column name with the regex pattern of `^\d+_X94?` with a value that matches the `fruit_list` data frame, it replaces the column name with the regex pattern of `^\d+_X38` with the word "green."

I currently have the following code, but I want to add some of the automated aspects so I don't have to list all the fruits in the `str_detect()` and create multiple `mutate` commands for X1, X2, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    X1_X38 = case_when(
      str_detect(X1_X94, "apple|watermelon") ~ "green",
      TRUE ~ .$X1_X38
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    X2_X38 = case_when(
      str_detect(X2_X94, "apple|watermelon") ~ "green",
      TRUE ~ .$X2_X38
    )
  )
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with('_X38'),
    ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA_character_ else 
     case_when(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "_X38$", "_X94")) %in% 
    fruit ~ "green", TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
   X1_X94     X2_X94 X1_X09 X2_X09 X1_X38 X2_X38
1  apple      apple      1      4  green  green
2  lemon strawberry      2      5 yellow    red
3 orange      lemon      3      6 orange yellow
```

Comment: The code errors out if a column only has NAs. Is there a way to ignore that?

Answer (score 1):

This does not feel like the most efficient way, but here is an option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df|>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(names_pattern = "(X\\d)_(X\\d+)", 
               names_to = c("X1", "X2"),
               values_transform = as.character,
               cols = -row)|>
  pivot_wider(names_from = X2, values_from = value) |>
  mutate(X38 = ifelse(X94 %in% fruit_list$fruit, "green", X38)) |>
  pivot_longer(c(X38,X09, X94)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(X1, name), 
              names_glue = "{X1}_{name}", 
              values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>     row X1_X38 X1_X09 X1_X94 X2_X38 X2_X09 X2_X94    
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1     1 green  1      apple  green  4      apple     
#> 2     2 yellow 2      lemon  red    5      strawberry
#> 3     3 orange 3      orange yellow 6      lemon
```

EDIT

This feels a little cleaner:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#helper
col_split <- function(dat){
  list(
    dat[,grepl("X1_", colnames(dat))],
    dat[,grepl("X2_", colnames(dat))]
  )
}

df |>
  col_split() |>
  map_dfc(\(x) mutate(x, across(ends_with("X38"), 
                                \(y) ifelse(x[,grepl("X94", colnames(x))] %in% fruit_list$fruit, 
                                            "green", y))))
#>   X1_X94 X1_X09 X1_X38     X2_X94 X2_X09 X2_X38
#> 1  apple      1  green      apple      4  green
#> 2  lemon      2 yellow strawberry      5    red
#> 3 orange      3 orange      lemon      6 yellow
```

Comment: Is there a way to refer to X1, X2, etc. in `col_split` that doesn't require me typing out  X1, X2,..., Xn?